# Function counter JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Please help: I want to create a function counter but I have a problem in my code. Don't give me a solution just correct my mistakes.

Here's my code

**JavaScript**

```
var j=0;
var i=0;
function chrono(){
    if (i==0){
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="un.JPG";
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="deux.JPG";         
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="trois.JPG";
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="quatre.JPG";
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="cinq.JPG";
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="six.JPG";          
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="sept.JPG";         
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="huit.JPG";         
        i++;
        document.frm.image1.src="neuf.JPG"; 
        i=0;
        document.frm.image1.src="zero.JPG";
        j++;
        if(j==1){
            document.frm.image0.src="un.JPG";
        }
        if (j==2){
            document.frm.image0.src="deux.JPG";
        }
        if (j==3){
            document.frm.image0.src="trois.JPG";
        }
        if (j==4){
            document.frm.image0.src="quatre.JPG";
        }
        if (j==5){
        document.frm.image0.src="cinq.JPG";
        }
        if (j==6){
            document.frm.image0.src="six.JPG";
        }
        if (j==7){
            document.frm.image0.src="sept.JPG";
        }
        if (j==8){
        document.frm.image0.src="huit.JPG";
        }
        if (j==9){
            document.frm.image0.src="neuf.JPG";
            j=0;
        }
    }
        setTimeout('chrono',100);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="frm">
   <img name="image0" src="zero.JPG" align="left" >
   <img name="image1" src="zero.JPG" align="left" ><br> <br>
   <input type="button" name="bot1" value="Debut" onclick="chrono()">
   <input type="button" name="bot2" value="Stop" onclick="">
</form>
```

Comment: Please don't tell people to shut up. You should format your source code before submitting the question otherwise it makes it very difficult to read and most people will just downvote your question and not bother to take time to read it.

Comment: @NizarElhraiech Flagged you for being rude. If you expect to get free help from people, treat them with respect. Oh, and "Does this look *good* to you", is what I meant to ask.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're facing?

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do there - it does not really make any sense. Why are you using a `setTimeout`? What is the purpose of `i` and `j`?

Comment: He want to do a chronometer, where image here are a number. Think i for  hundredth and j for seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration in the for loop is wrong.

The `setTimeout` function calls a function after a specific time frame. Your problem is that every execution iterates `i` from `0 to 9`.